# Arduino frequency meter

Tags: arduino, frequency

I'm new to Arduino and was making a frequency counter using the pulseIn function.

The problem I'm facing is that the output values are very absurd, such as 66334, 883339,12, 34 etc. and not the actual frequency.

I'm using a 1kHz square wave from a 555 (shows perfect on the oscilloscope.)

Here is the code:

```
int in_pin=2;
float t_high;
float t_low;
float t_total;
float freq;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(in_pin,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  t_high=pulseIn(in_pin,HIGH);
  t_low=pulseIn(in_pin,LOW);
  t_total=t_high + t_low;
  freq= 1000000.0/t_total;
  Serial.println(freq);
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Select the code and click the `{}` code formatting button. Make sure your indentation is correct. Add comments.

Comment: I think you have over simplified things. Read some paper about period and frequency measurement and how to do this in MCU. The signal transition has to trigger an interrupt and then ...Using a  pre-made function that you don't understand is a no go.

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.PulseIn):

> Please also note that if the pin is already high when the function is called, it will wait for the pin to go LOW and then HIGH before it starts counting.

Although not stated very clearly, this means that your code is working like this. It has to wait for the next low pulse to measure that. It shouldn't matter in your application.

```
          ______           ______           ______
_________|      |_________|      |_________|      |______
         <------>                <--------->
          t_low                    t_high
```

> This routine can be used only if interrupts are activated. [pulseIn()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.PulseIn).

I don't see any interrupt use in your code.

> Furthermore the highest resolution is obtained with short intervals.

You'll need to read up on this.

Note also that the function `pulseIn()` returns a data type of *unsigned long*, not *float* as you have used.

Comment: Thanks for reply transistor, sorry i wrote t_high in place of t_low and vice versa...and I've tried unsigned long as well...but still got absurd output.. :((

Comment: And the interrupts ...?

Comment: What interrupts?? 

Comment: I read it on https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.PulseIn. I don't know any more than that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Transistor's comment above (mismatched data types), there's also the issue about whether interrupts should be on or off - and which pulseIn() you should be using. You seem to be following: https://www.electronicshub.org/frequency-counter-using-arduino/. I'd suggest starting with their exact code (note the variable type declarations).

Additionally, there are two "pulseIn" functions in arduino pulseIn() and pulseInLong(). https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/pulsein/ and https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/pulseinlong/. Both return unsigned long integers, but you declared them as floats. You can try using either pulseIn() or pulseInLong() and see which works better. I think interrupts are on by default, so as long as you don't turn them off, pulseInLong() works. The other (pulseIn) works whether or not interrupts are on (according to the documentation). That said, at least one experiment should that pulseOn is more accurate with interrupts off: https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/arduino-pulsein.html .

Finally, if you're trying to make a frequency counter, I'd suggest using interrupts (https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/pulse-counting/interrupt-based-pulse-counter) or use atmega's built in counter register that is designed exactly for that (for example: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=59779.msg438414#msg438414, but there has to be other examples out there too).